# Problem using doclicense, academicons and authblk

Tags: authblk, academicons

The example document below presents a strange behavior when using `doclicense`, `academicons` and `authblk`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by},version={4.0}]{doclicense}
\author[1]{Teste123 \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\aiOrcid} \thanks{Email:\url{test@test.com}}}
\affil[1]{Stack Test}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Lorem ipsum
\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon
\end{document}
```

Notice the sequence `m, 1[]1Stack Test„` produced in the end.

[image]

Comment: academicons is not meant for pdflatex. You should actually get an error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using xelatex.

Comment: Why are you using `inputenc` then?

Comment: @Ingmar it's just ignored... that is not what is causing the problem anyway

Comment: Does not produce stray chars in Lualatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dunno why, but `\protect\aiOrcid` fixes it.

I noted in a comment that Lualatex did not suffer the same issue...only Xelatex.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by},version={4.0}]{doclicense}
\author[1]{Teste123 
  \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\protect\aiOrcid} 
  \thanks{Email:\url{test@test.com}}}
\affil[1]{Stack Test}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Lorem ipsum
\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the pdfauthor with `\hypersetup`, then hyperref will  not try to extract it from the author command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor = whatever} %<--------------
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[type={CC},modifier={by},version={4.0}]{doclicense}
\author[1]{Teste123 \href{https://orcid.org/0000-0000-0000-0000}{\aiOrcid} \thanks{Email:\url{test@test.com}}}
\affil[1]{Stack Test}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Lorem ipsum
\doclicenseText\par\doclicenseIcon
\end{document}
```

The breaklinks option is unneeded.